# Return ManyToOne list in JPQL query in Spring Data JPA Repository

Tags: java, spring, jpql

I have a relatively simple domain model concerning books in a Spring Boot 2 application with PostgreSQL.

Simple case is that multiple books belong to a series (with ordering), e.g. Lord of the Rings 1, Lord of the Rings 2 etc.

My domain entities are

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "seriesentity")
public class SeriesEntity {    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @NotNull
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String title;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "series")
    @OrderColumn(name = "series_index")
    private List<BookEntity> books;

    //Getters and Setters left out
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "book")
public class BookEntity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @NotNull
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String title;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="series_id")
    private SeriesEntity series;

    //Getters/setters and other unimportant properties left out
}
```

I *also* have a “DTO” which I want to retrieve directly from the database, which I can then use in the frontend:

```
public class SeriesDto {
    private Long id;
    private String title;
    private Locale locale;
    private List<Book> books;

    public SeriesDto(Long id, String title, Locale locale, List<Book> books) {
        this.id = id;
        this.title = title;
        this.locale = locale;
        this.books = books;
    }

    public static class Book {
        private Long id;
        private String title;

        public Book(Long id, String title) {
            this.id = id;
            this.title = title;
        }
    }
}
```

Creating the dto without the books works (tested in the JPA console of IntelliJ):

`SELECT new series.query.SeriesDto(s.id, s.title, s.locale) FROM SeriesEntity s WHERE s.id = :id`

But how can I map the OneToMany relationship?

`SELECT distinct s.id as series_id, s.title, s.locale, books FROM SeriesEntity s INNER JOIN s.books books WHERE s.id = :id`

This returns multiple rows, for example:

```
1   Lord of the Rings   de  46  Der Herr der Ringe Band 1: Die Gefährten    1   Lord of the Rings   de
1   Lord of the Rings   de  47  Der Herr der Ringe Band 2: Die zwei Türme   1   Lord of the Rings   de
```

Another problem is that it will return the series information again because it is linked to Book entity.

Is there any way to aggregate this automatically in JPQL, so that I do not have to write a Java method? Or can I at least provide a mapping function?

Thanks!

Comment: What rows are returned?

Comment: In my memory,there is able to query with a `child query`,may you try ?

Answer (score 1):

You should use:

```
SELECT new series.query.SeriesDto(s.id, s.title, s.locale, s.books)
FROM SeriesEntity s 
WHERE s.id = :id
```

You can see the query log: cross join (yours is inner join)